# Ice accretion on Structures in Canada

Tags: structural-engineering, civil-engineering

Section 3.12.6 of CSA-S6-06 mentions that

> "Ice accretion load shall be taken on all exposed surface of superstructure members, structural supports, traffic signals, luminairies and
>   railings. In case of sign panels, bridge girders, and solid barriers,
>   ice accretion shall be considered to occur on one side only".

Why in the latter part of the above statement, ice accretion is considered to occur only on one side?

Answer (score 3):

Because if ice accretion occurred equally on both sides there would not be a turning moment or side load on one side compared to the other. Having seen ice accretion on trees, lamp posts it is on one side only, normally due to the wind prevailing at that time.

Comment: So does that mean for all heights the turning moment is critical compared to the buckling that might occur if the ice load is considered throughout the aforementioned structure/objects. Also please note the ellipsis in my question would open to "...superstructure members, structural supports, traffic signals, luminaries and railings. In case..."

Comment: If you add mass - weight to one side of a structure then that is what can cause buckling of the material or it falling over so you have to design for all conditions. I don't do this, but that is what I get from reading the section you quoted.